# JavaScript code inside HTML script tag not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access the names of the files in a particular path. The JavaScript code written separately works fine whereas when it is put inside the HTML, the code doesn't works.

```
fs = require('fs');
var directory = 'IPIE/';//direcory name(path name)

fs.readdir(directory, (err, files)=> {
   for (index in files) {
      console.log(files[index]);
   }
});
```

This code gives the output i.e., the folder names as below:

```
BigBubbles
Edgegap
Sticky
```

Whereas the html code below doesn't work fine

```
<html>
   <body>
      <label>Input Option:</label>
      <select id="input_mode"></select>
      <button onclick='displayfiles()'>abc</button>
   </body>    

   <script>
      function displayfiles() {
         var fs = require('fs');
         var directory = 'IPIE/'; //folder name

         fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
            var select = document.getElementById("input_mode");
            for (index in files) {
               select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(files[index], index);
            }
         });
      }
   </script>
</html>
```

And I noticed after   `var fs = require('fs');`   line, `alert("something")` doesn't work which means the execution stops at that line..???
Please help

Comment: 'fs' is a Node.js Module, it's normal that doesn't work on browser.

Comment: @yip102011 Oh! Thanks.. Is there any other procedure to access the file names via html?

Comment: Also `require` does not work on a browser. And next, the browser is not allowed to access the file system (thankfully!!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order output the file list, you have to setup a web server, get the file list in server side then output to browser. Execute and access http://localhost/

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });

    var fileSelectHtml = getFileSelectHtml();
    res.end(`
            <html>
                <body>
                    <label>Input Option:</label>
                    ${fileSelectHtml}
                </body>
            </html>
            `); 

}).listen(80);

function getFileSelectHtml() {
    var files = fs.readdirSync('IPIE/');

    var selectHtml = '<select id="input_mode">';
    for (index in files) {
       selectHtml += '<option>'+ files[index] +'</option>';
    }
    selectHtml += '</select>';
    return selectHtml;
}
```